# virt-install and qemu-system-aarch64: cannot create vmnet interface: general failure (possibly not enough privileges)

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I'm trying to `virt-install` the following:

```
sudo virt-install \                             1
--name host1 \
--memory 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \
--disk size=30 \
--cdrom ./box.img \
--os-variant ubuntu22.04 \
--virt-type hvf \
--qemu-commandline='-M highmem=off -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=54:54:00:55:54:51' \
--network user
```

and I got the following error:

```
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-01-12T01:08:04.782892Z qemu-system-aarch64: -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0: cannot create vmnet interface: general failure (possibly not enough privileges)
```

I've tried to run both libvirtd manually and via the `brew services`, and I got the same error.

```
# when I run as a local user
/opt/homebrew/opt/libvirt/sbin/libvirtd -f /opt/homebrew/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf
```

```
# via homebrew services 
◼ ~ $ brew services
Name             Status  User File
libvirt          started root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.libvirt.plist
```

and this is the libvirtd.conf:

```
# Master libvirt daemon configuration file
#

#################################################################
#
# Network connectivity controls
#

# Flag listening for secure TLS connections on the public TCP/IP port.
#
# To enable listening sockets with the 'libvirtd' daemon it's also required to
# pass the '--listen' flag on the commandline of the daemon.
# This is not needed with 'virtproxyd'.
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# It is necessary to setup a CA and issue server certificates before
# using this capability.
#
# This is enabled by default, uncomment this to disable it
#listen_tls = 0

# Listen for unencrypted TCP connections on the public TCP/IP port.
#
# To enable listening sockets with the 'libvirtd' daemon it's also required to
# pass the '--listen' flag on the commandline of the daemon.
# This is not needed with 'virtproxyd'.
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# Using the TCP socket requires SASL authentication by default. Only
# SASL mechanisms which support data encryption are allowed. This is
# DIGEST_MD5 and GSSAPI (Kerberos5)
#
# This is disabled by default, uncomment this to enable it.
#listen_tcp = 1



# Override the port for accepting secure TLS connections
# This can be a port number, or service name
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
#tls_port = "16514"

# Override the port for accepting insecure TCP connections
# This can be a port number, or service name
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
#tcp_port = "16509"


# Override the default configuration which binds to all network
# interfaces. This can be a numeric IPv4/6 address, or hostname
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# If the libvirtd service is started in parallel with network
# startup (e.g. with systemd), binding to addresses other than
# the wildcards (0.0.0.0/::) might not be available yet.
#
#listen_addr = "192.168.0.1"


#################################################################
#
# UNIX socket access controls
#

# Set the UNIX domain socket group ownership. This can be used to
# allow a 'trusted' set of users access to management capabilities
# without becoming root.
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# This is restricted to 'root' by default.
#unix_sock_group = "libvirt"

# Set the UNIX socket permissions for the R/O socket. This is used
# for monitoring VM status only
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# Default allows any user. If setting group ownership, you may want to
# restrict this too.
unix_sock_ro_perms = "0777"

# Set the UNIX socket permissions for the R/W socket. This is used
# for full management of VMs
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# Default allows only root. If PolicyKit is enabled on the socket,
# the default will change to allow everyone (eg, 0777)
#
# If not using PolicyKit and setting group ownership for access
# control, then you may want to relax this too.
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"

# Set the UNIX socket permissions for the admin interface socket.
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
# Default allows only owner (root), do not change it unless you are
# sure to whom you are exposing the access to.
unix_sock_admin_perms = "0700"

# Set the name of the directory in which sockets will be found/created.
#
# This setting is not required or honoured if using systemd socket
# activation.
#
unix_sock_dir = "/opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt"



#################################################################
#
# Authentication.
#
# There are the following choices available:
#
#  - none: do not perform auth checks. If you can connect to the
#          socket you are allowed. This is suitable if there are
#          restrictions on connecting to the socket (eg, UNIX
#          socket permissions), or if there is a lower layer in
#          the network providing auth (eg, TLS/x509 certificates)
#
#  - sasl: use SASL infrastructure. The actual auth scheme is then
#          controlled from /opt/homebrew/etc/sasl2/libvirt.conf. For the TCP
#          socket only GSSAPI & DIGEST-MD5 mechanisms will be used.
#          For non-TCP or TLS sockets, any scheme is allowed.
#
#  - polkit: use PolicyKit to authenticate. This is only suitable
#            for use on the UNIX sockets. The default policy will
#            require a user to supply their own password to gain
#            full read/write access (aka sudo like), while anyone
#            is allowed read/only access.
#

# Set an authentication scheme for UNIX read-only sockets
#
# By default socket permissions allow anyone to connect
#
# If libvirt was compiled without support for 'polkit', then
# no access control checks are done, but libvirt still only
# allows execution of APIs which don't change state.
#
# If libvirt was compiled with support for 'polkit', then
# the libvirt socket will perform a check with polkit after
# connections. The default policy still allows any local
# user access.
#
# To restrict monitoring of domains you may wish to either
# enable 'sasl' here, or change the polkit policy definition.
#auth_unix_ro = "none"

# Set an authentication scheme for UNIX read-write sockets.
#
# If libvirt was compiled without support for 'polkit', then
# the systemd .socket files will use SocketMode=0600 by default
# thus only allowing root user to connect, and 'auth_unix_rw'
# will default to 'none'.
#
# If libvirt was compiled with support for 'polkit', then
# the systemd .socket files will use SocketMode=0666 which
# allows any user to connect and 'auth_unix_rw' will default
# to 'polkit'. If you disable use of 'polkit' here, then it
# is essential to change the systemd SocketMode parameter
# back to 0600, to avoid an insecure configuration.
#
#auth_unix_rw = "none"

# Change the authentication scheme for TCP sockets.
#
# If you don't enable SASL, then all TCP traffic is cleartext.
# Don't do this outside of a dev/test scenario. For real world
# use, always enable SASL and use the GSSAPI or DIGEST-MD5
# mechanism in /opt/homebrew/etc/sasl2/libvirt.conf
#auth_tcp = "sasl"

# Change the authentication scheme for TLS sockets.
#
# TLS sockets already have encryption provided by the TLS
# layer, and limited authentication is done by certificates
#
# It is possible to make use of any SASL authentication
# mechanism as well, by using 'sasl' for this option
#auth_tls = "none"

# Enforce a minimum SSF value for TCP sockets
#
# The default minimum is currently 56 (single-DES) which will
# be raised to 112 in the future.
#
# This option can be used to set values higher than 112
#tcp_min_ssf = 112


# Change the API access control scheme
#
# By default an authenticated user is allowed access
# to all APIs. Access drivers can place restrictions
# on this. By default the 'nop' driver is enabled,
# meaning no access control checks are done once a
# client has authenticated with libvirtd
#
#access_drivers = [ "polkit" ]

#################################################################
#
# TLS x509 certificate configuration
#

# Use of TLS requires that x509 certificates be issued. The default locations
# for the certificate files is as follows:
#
#   /opt/homebrew/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem - The CA master certificate
#   /opt/homebrew/etc/pki/libvirt/servercert.pem - The server certificate signed by cacert.pem
#   /opt/homebrew/etc/pki/libvirt/private/serverkey.pem - The server private key
#
# It is possible to override the default locations by altering the 'key_file',
# 'cert_file', and 'ca_file' values and uncommenting them below.
#
# NB, overriding the default of one location requires uncommenting and
# possibly additionally overriding the other settings.
#

# Override the default server key file path
#
#key_file = "/opt/homebrew/etc/pki/libvirt/private/serverkey.pem"

# Override the default server certificate file path
#
#cert_file = "/opt/homebrew/etc/pki/libvirt/servercert.pem"

# Override the default CA certificate path
#
#ca_file = "/opt/homebrew/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem"

# Specify a certificate revocation list.
#
# Defaults to not using a CRL, uncomment to enable it
#crl_file = "/opt/homebrew/etc/pki/CA/crl.pem"



#################################################################
#
# Authorization controls
#


# Flag to disable verification of our own server certificates
#
# When libvirtd starts it performs some sanity checks against
# its own certificates.
#
# Default is to always run sanity checks. Uncommenting this
# will disable sanity checks which is not a good idea
#tls_no_sanity_certificate = 1

# Flag to disable verification of client certificates
#
# Client certificate verification is the primary authentication mechanism.
# Any client which does not present a certificate signed by the CA
# will be rejected.
#
# Default is to always verify. Uncommenting this will disable
# verification.
#tls_no_verify_certificate = 1


# An access control list of allowed x509 Distinguished Names
# This list may contain wildcards such as
#
#    "C=GB,ST=London,L=London,O=Red Hat,CN=*"
#
# Any * matches any number of consecutive spaces, like a simplified glob(7).
#
# The format of the DN for a particular certificate can be queried
# using:
#
#    virt-pki-query-dn clientcert.pem
#
# NB If this is an empty list, no client can connect, so comment out
# entirely rather than using empty list to disable these checks
#
# By default, no DN's are checked
#tls_allowed_dn_list = ["DN1", "DN2"]


# Override the compile time default TLS priority string. The
# default is usually "NORMAL" unless overridden at build time.
# Only set this is it is desired for libvirt to deviate from
# the global default settings.
#
#tls_priority="NORMAL"


# An access control list of allowed SASL usernames. The format for username
# depends on the SASL authentication mechanism. Kerberos usernames
# look like username@REALM
#
# This list may contain wildcards such as
#
#    "*@EXAMPLE.COM"
#
# See the g_pattern_match function for the format of the wildcards.
#
# https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Glob-style-pattern-matching.html
#
# NB If this is an empty list, no client can connect, so comment out
# entirely rather than using empty list to disable these checks
#
# By default, no Username's are checked
#sasl_allowed_username_list = ["joe@EXAMPLE.COM", "fred@EXAMPLE.COM" ]


#################################################################
#
# Processing controls
#

# The maximum number of concurrent client connections to allow
# over all sockets combined.
#max_clients = 5000

# The maximum length of queue of connections waiting to be
# accepted by the daemon. Note, that some protocols supporting
# retransmission may obey this so that a later reattempt at
# connection succeeds.
#max_queued_clients = 1000

# The maximum length of queue of accepted but not yet
# authenticated clients. The default value is 20. Set this to
# zero to turn this feature off.
#max_anonymous_clients = 20

# The minimum limit sets the number of workers to start up
# initially. If the number of active clients exceeds this,
# then more threads are spawned, up to max_workers limit.
# Typically you'd want max_workers to equal maximum number
# of clients allowed
#min_workers = 5
#max_workers = 20


# The number of priority workers. If all workers from above
# pool are stuck, some calls marked as high priority
# (notably domainDestroy) can be executed in this pool.
#prio_workers = 5

# Limit on concurrent requests from a single client
# connection. To avoid one client monopolizing the server
# this should be a small fraction of the global max_workers
# parameter.
#max_client_requests = 5

# Same processing controls, but this time for the admin interface.
# For description of each option, be so kind to scroll few lines
# upwards.

#admin_min_workers = 1
#admin_max_workers = 5
#admin_max_clients = 5
#admin_max_queued_clients = 5
#admin_max_client_requests = 5

#################################################################
#
# Logging controls
#

# Logging level: 4 errors, 3 warnings, 2 information, 1 debug
# basically 1 will log everything possible
#
# WARNING: USE OF THIS IS STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.
#
# WARNING: It outputs too much information to practically read.
# WARNING: The "log_filters" setting is recommended instead.
#
# WARNING: Journald applies rate limiting of messages and so libvirt
# WARNING: will limit "log_level" to only allow values 3 or 4 if
# WARNING: journald is the current output.
#
# WARNING: USE OF THIS IS STRONGLY DISCOURAGED.
#log_level = 3

# Logging filters:
# A filter allows to select a different logging level for a given category
# of logs. The format for a filter is:
#
#    level:match
#
# where 'match' is a string which is matched against the category
# given in the VIR_LOG_INIT() at the top of each libvirt source
# file, e.g., "remote", "qemu", or "util.json". The 'match' in the
# filter matches using shell wildcard syntax (see 'man glob(7)').
# The 'match' is always treated as a substring match. IOW a match
# string 'foo' is equivalent to '*foo*'.
#
# 'level' is the minimal level where matching messages should
#  be logged:
#
#    1: DEBUG
#    2: INFO
#    3: WARNING
#    4: ERROR
#
# Multiple filters can be defined in a single @log_filters, they just need
# to be separated by spaces. Note that libvirt performs "first" match, i.e.
# if there are concurrent filters, the first one that matches will be applied,
# given the order in @log_filters.
#
# A typical need is to capture information from a hypervisor driver,
# public API entrypoints and some of the utility code. Some utility
# code is very verbose and is generally not desired. Taking the QEMU
# hypervisor as an example, a suitable filter string for debugging
# might be to turn off object, json & event logging, but enable the
# rest of the util code:
#
#log_filters="1:qemu 1:libvirt 4:object 4:json 4:event 1:util"

# Logging outputs:
# An output is one of the places to save logging information
# The format for an output can be:
#    level:stderr
#      output goes to stderr
#    level:syslog:name
#      use syslog for the output and use the given name as the ident
#    level:file:file_path
#      output to a file, with the given filepath
#    level:journald
#      output to journald logging system
# In all cases 'level' is the minimal priority, acting as a filter
#    1: DEBUG
#    2: INFO
#    3: WARNING
#    4: ERROR
#
# Multiple outputs can be defined, they just need to be separated by spaces.
# e.g. to log all warnings and errors to syslog under the libvirtd ident:
#log_outputs="3:syslog:libvirtd"


##################################################################
#
# Auditing
#
# This setting allows usage of the auditing subsystem to be altered:
#
#   audit_level == 0  -> disable all auditing
#   audit_level == 1  -> enable auditing, only if enabled on host (default)
#   audit_level == 2  -> enable auditing, and exit if disabled on host
#
#audit_level = 2
#
# If set to 1, then audit messages will also be sent
# via libvirt logging infrastructure. Defaults to 0
#
#audit_logging = 1

###################################################################
# UUID of the host:
# Host UUID is read from one of the sources specified in host_uuid_source.
#
# - 'smbios': fetch the UUID from 'dmidecode -s system-uuid'
# - 'machine-id': fetch the UUID from /etc/machine-id
#
# The host_uuid_source default is 'smbios'. If 'dmidecode' does not provide
# a valid UUID a temporary UUID will be generated.
#
# Another option is to specify host UUID in host_uuid.
#
# Keep the format of the example UUID below. UUID must not have all digits
# be the same.

# NB This default all-zeros UUID will not work. Replace
# it with the output of the 'uuidgen' command and then
# uncomment this entry
#host_uuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
#host_uuid_source = "smbios"

###################################################################
# Keepalive protocol:
# This allows libvirtd to detect broken client connections or even
# dead clients.  A keepalive message is sent to a client after
# keepalive_interval seconds of inactivity to check if the client is
# still responding; keepalive_count is a maximum number of keepalive
# messages that are allowed to be sent to the client without getting
# any response before the connection is considered broken.  In other
# words, the connection is automatically closed approximately after
# keepalive_interval * (keepalive_count + 1) seconds since the last
# message received from the client.  If keepalive_interval is set to
# -1, libvirtd will never send keepalive requests; however clients
# can still send them and the daemon will send responses.  When
# keepalive_count is set to 0, connections will be automatically
# closed after keepalive_interval seconds of inactivity without
# sending any keepalive messages.
#
#keepalive_interval = 5
#keepalive_count = 5

#
# These configuration options are no longer used.  There is no way to
# restrict such clients from connecting since they first need to
# connect in order to ask for keepalive.
#
#keepalive_required = 1
#admin_keepalive_required = 1

# Keepalive settings for the admin interface
#admin_keepalive_interval = 5
#admin_keepalive_count = 5

###################################################################
# Open vSwitch:
# This allows to specify a timeout for openvswitch calls made by
# libvirt. The ovs-vsctl utility is used for the configuration and
# its timeout option is set by default to 5 seconds to avoid
# potential infinite waits blocking libvirt.
#
#
```

Now, to make sure that was a privilege error, I ran:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0 -machine virt-2.10
```

which reproduces the error, but:

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0 -machine virt-2.10
```

opens a qemu window and I got:

```
qemu-system-aarch64: warning: netdev net0 has no peer
```

alright, how could I fix libvirt on Mac OS, installed via homebrew?

```
$ brew info libvirt                               1
==> libvirt: stable 8.10.0 (bottled), HEAD
C virtualization API
https://libvirt.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libvirt/8.10.0 (587 files, 40.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2023-01-11 at 19:20:38
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/libvirt.rb
License: LGPL-2.1-or-later and GPL-2.0-or-later
==> Dependencies
Build: docutils ✘, meson ✘, ninja ✘, perl ✘, pkg-config ✔, python@3.11 ✔, rpcgen ✘
Required: gettext ✔, glib ✔, gnu-sed ✔, gnutls ✔, grep ✔, libgcrypt ✔, libiscsi ✔, libssh2 ✔, yajl ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To restart libvirt after an upgrade:
  brew services restart libvirt
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/libvirt/sbin/libvirtd -f /opt/homebrew/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf
==> Analytics
install: 4,452 (30 days), 18,333 (90 days), 69,415 (365 days)
install-on-request: 3,222 (30 days), 13,494 (90 days), 52,022 (365 days)
build-error: 4 (30 days)
```

---

**Update**

Maybe I've found the source of the problem [here](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/1364), if anyone could confirm

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry I know this has been a while but I'm setting up my first Mac in quite a few years and I'm going through this. I want to first clarify the difference between the qemu and libvirtd. Running a machine manually with qemu-system-* doesn't actually touch libvirt, so the version of that won't affect behaviour here. Running a QEMU VM via libvirt/virt-manager will have implications as libvirt will decided what qemu command to run based on your XML config for a VM.

There are two problems here. First is the permissions issue which you identified. You can do this either running QEMU as root (not ideal) or for my purposes and using libvirt, just changing permissions on the libvirtd socket to allow admins access (my admins have sudo anyway):

```
sudo chmod 760 /opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
```

Now admins can access the QEMU:///system path instead of just QEMU:///session for users. This differs from Linux with its dedicated group for this kind of thing. Homebrew ships with the socket owned by root:admins with 0700 permissions for security, similar to early Docker socket only allowing root. Beware any security issues of opening this socket to admins and letting your QEMU VMs be run with elevated privileges/root.

The second issue is you have no device declared to attach the netdev to, so is it a PCI slot? What bus? Etc. Unfortunately QEMU doesn't always make this clear but virt-manager makes it easier with a helpful GUI when using libvirt.

If you add a device with the netdev it should work. Here I pick PCI slot 8 on the default bus. Change to whatever available PCI slot you want.

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -device virtio-net,netdev=net0,mac=[create your MAC],addr=0x8 -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0 -machine virt-2.10
```

Also note that the virt-manager and libvirt domain schemas that currently ship with libvirt on homebrew don't actually support the Mac `vmnet*` device types yet. I actually tried editing these myself but something is still not having an effect so will need to dig further.  In the meantime you can edit your libvirt VM XML manually in virt-manager to add manual qemu args to add them.
First you may need to set the schema manually to the official QEMU one at the top of your XML:

```
<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="hvf">
```

Then at the bottom of the domain you can manually add arbitrary args:

```
<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
  <qemu:arg value="virtio-net,netdev=example1,mac=52:54:00:9b:b7:34,addr=0xA"/>
  <qemu:arg value="-netdev"/>
  <qemu:arg value="vmnet-host,id=example1/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

Who doesn't love a bit of nostalgic XML right? It's ugly but until the schemas add vmnet* support in Homebrew then this is what's required to add an extra NIC with host-VM access on Mac libvirt. You can verify your command runs correctly via a `ps -ef | grep qemu` to see how it actually gets run. Otherwise virt-manager or libvirt will throw python stack traces until it understands what you're trying to do.

The domain schemas in my Mac are stored in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libvirt/9.8.0/share/libvirt/schemas/domaincommon.rng` but adding vmnet-host to it didn't work for me as some other system seemed to be double-blocking me. I'm used to Linux packaging so maybe something else is going on if someone can pitch in.

One additional note - since Spice is being deprecated, VNC is the only supported native virt-manager GUI option on Macs. It works fair enough but isn't high performance and leaves artifacts. Once you add a host nic you can use SSH X forwarding or NX or better yet RDP to connect to a VM. I find accessing my local Linux VMs via RDP over a vmnet-host interface performs superbly.